# relationship using with() in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have two Model i.e., staff and attendance, and
attendance table have staff_id

so in controller I want to display all staff with the relation of attendance like below

```
Staff::with('attendance')->get();
```

but the attendance should be formatted based on month selected

Is there any way to check the month value in my code like (where(attendance->month == request()->month)) or have to check the month in blade file (or another line)

thanks in advance and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$month = //month;
$data = Staff::with(['attendance', function($query) use ($month) {
                $query->where('month', $month);
              }])->get();
```

Let me know if it help you!

Comment: almost working, but it gives me the idea of how to use.. and now I can display like what I want. Thanks

Comment: it should be like `with(['attendance' => function($query) use ($month) {}])`

Answer (score 1):

```
you can do the following:

$condition = '';
$data = Staff::whereHas('attendance',function($q) use($condition){
   $q->where('month',$condition);
})->get();
```

Comment: you can do it with only `whereHas()` or `with()` so what is the need of `with()` + `whereHas` ??

Comment: I forgot the with I will remove it